# Controlling parser rule alternatives precedence

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have an expression `IF 1 THEN 2 ELSE 3 * 4`. I want this parsed as `IF 1 THEN 2 ELSE (3 * 4)`, however using my grammar (extract) below, it parses it as `(IF 1 THEN 2 ELSE 3) * 4`.

```
formula: expression EOF;

expression
   : LPAREN expression RPAREN #parenthesisExp
   | IF condition=expression THEN thenExpression=expression ELSE elseExpression=expression #ifExp
   | left=expression BINARYOPERATOR right=expression #binaryoperationExp
   | left=expression op=(TIMES|DIV) right=expression    #muldivExp
   | left=expression op=(PLUS|MINUS) right=expression    #addsubtractExp
   | left=expression op=(EQUALS|NOTEQUALS|LT|GT) right=expression #comparisonExp
   | left=expression AMPERSAND right=expression #concatenateExp
   | NOT expression #notExp
   | STRINGLITERAL #stringliteralExp
   | signedAtom #atomExp
   ;
```

My understanding is that because I have the `ifExp` alternative appearing before the `muldivExp` it should use that first, then because I have the `muldivExp` before `atomExp` (which handles numbers) it should do `3 * 4` to end the ELSE, rather than using just the `3`. In which case I can't see why it's making the `IF..THEN..ELSE` a child of the multiplication.

---

I don't think the rest of the grammar is relevant here, but in case it is see below for the whole thing.

```
grammar AnaplanFormula;

formula: expression EOF;

expression
   : LPAREN expression RPAREN #parenthesisExp
   | IF condition=expression THEN thenExpression=expression ELSE elseExpression=expression #ifExp
   | left=expression BINARYOPERATOR right=expression #binaryoperationExp
   | left=expression op=(TIMES|DIV) right=expression    #muldivExp
   | left=expression op=(PLUS|MINUS) right=expression    #addsubtractExp
   | left=expression op=(EQUALS|NOTEQUALS|LT|GT) right=expression #comparisonExp
   | left=expression AMPERSAND right=expression #concatenateExp
   | NOT expression #notExp
   | STRINGLITERAL #stringliteralExp
   | signedAtom #atomExp
   ;

signedAtom
   : PLUS signedAtom #plusSignedAtom
   | MINUS signedAtom #minusSignedAtom
   | func_ #funcAtom
   | atom #atomAtom
   ;

atom
   : SCIENTIFIC_NUMBER #numberAtom
   | LPAREN expression RPAREN #expressionAtom // Do we need this?
   | entity #entityAtom
   ;

func_: functionname LPAREN (expression (',' expression)*)? RPAREN #funcParameterised
   | entity LSQUARE dimensionmapping (',' dimensionmapping)* RSQUARE #funcSquareBrackets
   ;

dimensionmapping: WORD COLON entity; // Could make WORD more specific here

functionname: WORD; // Could make WORD more specific here

entity: QUOTELITERAL #quotedEntity
   | WORD+ #wordsEntity
   | left=entity DOT right=entity #dotQualifiedEntity
   ;

WS: [ \r\n\t]+ -> skip;

/////////////////
//  Fragments  //
/////////////////

fragment NUMBER: DIGIT+ (DOT DIGIT+)?;

fragment DIGIT: [0-9];
fragment LOWERCASE: [a-z];
fragment UPPERCASE: [A-Z];
fragment WORDSYMBOL: [#?_£%];

//////////////////
//    Tokens    //
//////////////////

IF: 'IF' | 'if';
THEN: 'THEN' | 'then';
ELSE: 'ELSE' | 'else';
BINARYOPERATOR: 'AND' | 'and' | 'OR' | 'or';
NOT: 'NOT' | 'not';

WORD: (DIGIT* (LOWERCASE | UPPERCASE | WORDSYMBOL)) (LOWERCASE | UPPERCASE | DIGIT | WORDSYMBOL)*;

STRINGLITERAL: DOUBLEQUOTES (~'"' | ('""'))* DOUBLEQUOTES;

QUOTELITERAL: '\'' (~'\'' | ('\'\''))* '\'';

LSQUARE: '[';
RSQUARE: ']';
LPAREN: '(';
RPAREN: ')';
PLUS: '+';
MINUS: '-';
TIMES: '*';
DIV: '/';
COLON: ':';
EQUALS: '=';
NOTEQUALS: LT GT;
LT: '<';
GT: '>';
AMPERSAND: '&';
DOUBLEQUOTES: '"';
UNDERSCORE: '_';
QUESTIONMARK: '?';
HASH: '#';
POUND: '£';
PERCENT: '%';
DOT: '.';
PIPE: '|';

SCIENTIFIC_NUMBER: NUMBER (('e' | 'E') (PLUS | MINUS)? NUMBER)?;
```

Comment: Interestingly, if I put the `#ifExp` alternative below the `#atomExp` one it appears to parse correctly, although that goes against my understanding of preference being given to alternatives declared first.

Comment: That actually makes sense.  You want to know the atom value before evaluating #ifExpr. Though the order won’t make a difference in that case.  My impression is that you’re thinking of precedence as “which rule should be higher in the tree”. That’s upside down. It’s “what should be evaluated (and it’s value resolved)” first at runtime. For 3+4*5 the tree will have the 3+ node at the top with the right node being 4*5 below it, so that the multiplication is done first (takes precedence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your `ifExpr` down near the end of your alternatives.  (In particular, below any alternative that you would wish to match your `elseExpression`

Your “if ... then ... else ...” is below the `muldivExp` precisely because you've made it a higher priority.  Items lower in the tree are evaluated before items higher in the tree, so higher priority items belong lower in the tree.

With:

```
expression:
    LPAREN expression RPAREN                                                                        # parenthesisExp
    | left = expression BINARYOPERATOR right = expression                                           # binaryoperationExp
    | left = expression op = (TIMES | DIV) right = expression                                       # muldivExp
    | left = expression op = (PLUS | MINUS) right = expression                                      # addsubtractExp
    | left = expression op = (EQUALS | NOTEQUALS | LT | GT) right = expression                      # comparisonExp
    | left = expression AMPERSAND right = expression                                                # concatenateExp
    | NOT expression                                                                                # notExp
    | STRINGLITERAL                                                                                 # stringliteralExp
    | signedAtom                                                                                    # atomExp
    | IF condition = expression THEN thenExpression = expression ELSE elseExpression = expression   #
        ifExp
    ;
```

I get

[image]